# How to put a button top-left and top-right of a table?

Tags: html, css

How to put button on up-left and up-rigth of a table? Something like this:

```
 |button-left|                     |button-right|
 |----------------table header------------------|
 |----------------table body--------------------|
 |----------------table body--------------------|
 |----------------table body--------------------|
 |----------------table body--------------------|
```

My html:

```
<div>
  <button class="btn btn-success" >Save</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" style="float: right;">Cancel</button>
  <div id="table"> 
    <table>.....</table>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my html looks like this:

```
 |button-left|                                               |button-right|
 |----------------table header------------------|
 |----------------table body--------------------|
 |----------------table body--------------------|
 |----------------table body--------------------|
 |----------------table body--------------------|
```

The table is auto created by datatables

Comment: more details about the table please... how many columns? I think it would be easiest to colspan half the columns for the button left and half for button right then add the buttons into the td elements and float them to left and right respectively.

Comment: The table is auto generated by datatables

Comment: Hey @Sato, can you please accept an answer to your question? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the `div` wrapping your table a class like `.table-wrapper` and add the following CSS

```css
.table-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}
.table-wrapper table {
  min-width: 120px;
}
```

Where `min-width` is the width of both ur buttons beside each other and maybe some extra space. This will make sure the buttons don't wrap and stay beside each other even when the table itself has little content.

Here is a [codepen example](http://cdpn.io/nhoqA). Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**

To avoid having to wrap the `.table-wrapper` and `table` in another `div` to get blocks again (see codepen), you can replace `display: inline-block` with `display: table`.

*Note:* This won't work on IE7 and below (see [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table)).

I also updated the Codepen example above to show both ways.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put the buttons inside another div with the same width as the table:

```
<div>
  <div style="width:(width);">
    <button class="btn btn-success" >Save</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" style="float: right;">Cancel</button>
  </div>
  <div id="table"> 
    <table>.....</table>
  </div>
</div>
```

where `(width)` is the width of the table.

Comment: But the width of table is not fixed. It's dynamically changing.

Comment: @Sato Is the width of the table determined by the table div? If it is you could try also putting the buttons inside of that div. How is the width of the table set?

Answer (score 0):

The default width of a `<div>` is 100% so you just need to give your bounding `<div>` a width attribute (in this case give it the width of the table).

Eg.

```
<div style="width: 500px">
  <button class="btn btn-success" >Save</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" style="float: right;">Cancel</button>
  <div id="table"> 
    <table width="500px">.....</table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**non-JS Solution:**

Use display to match up the widths (inline block for elements that need to fit to their contents and block for elements that should fit their parent)

```
<style>
        #table {display: inline-block;}
        #container {display: inline-block;}
        #buttons {display: block;}
    </style>

<div id="container">
<div id="buttons">
  <button class="btn btn-success" >Save</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" style="float: right;">Cancel</button>
</div>
  <div id="table"> 
    <table><tr><td>hello</td><td>column 2</td><td>hi again</td></tr><tr><td>hello</td><td>column 2</td><td>hi again</td></tr><tr><td>hello</td><td>column 2</td><td>hi again</td></tr></table>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**JS-Solution (not ideal):**

try this (I created a placeholder table to simulate the auto-created table)
- the display inline block css makes the container for the table size to the contents so that we can set the width of the buttons div to match it in the javascript following the table. If you dont want the JS inline you can put in in a script that fire after the DOM has loaded.

```
<style>
    #table {display: inline-block;}
</style>

<div>
<div id="buttons">
  <button class="btn btn-success" >Save</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" style="float: right;">Cancel</button>
 </div>
  <div id="table"> 
    <table><tr><td>hello</td><td>column 2</td><td>hi again</td></tr><tr><td>hello</td><td>column 2</td><td>hi again</td></tr><tr><td>hello</td><td>column 2</td><td>hi again</td></tr></table>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById('buttons').style.width = document.getElementById('table').clientWidth;
</script>
```

Comment: this is a simple styling issue - it doesn't require Javascript to solve.

Comment: Good point... I will edit my answer above with a non-JS solution

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the buttons in a div

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button class="btn btn-success" >Save</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" style="float: right;">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

apply a clear fix on the .buttons container and float the buttons

```
.buttons:after {
    clear:both;
    content:'';
    display:block;
}

.btn-success {
    float:left;
}

.btn-danger {
    float:right;
}
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46w5M/)

UPDATE:

You could add a class to the container div like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="buttons">
        ...
    </div>
    <table>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

and then add a float (or display: inline-block) to that container

```
.container {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
            /*display: inline-block;*/
}
```

here's the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46w5M/1/)

Comment: if the table isn't full-width (which the asker's isn't) then this does nothing to solve the problem.